# How To show variable as HTML in Django template?

Tags: python, django

let's said that I have function

```
def func(request):
    a="Hello, <br> this is my first app"
    return render_to_response(
                            'home.html',
                            {'a':a, 'request':request},
                            context_instance=RequestContext(request)
                          )
```

when I load variable a in home.html as

{{a}}

I will get Hello, `<br>` this is my first app , 
how to present `<br>` as new line in django template ...??

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
from django.utils.safestring import mark_safe


a = mark_safe("Hello, <br> this is my first app")
```

Django automatically escapes any HTML in your variables, so you need to mark it as a safestring.

Keep in mind, for example, that safestring + unsafestring = unsafestring.
You can read more about it [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/utils/#django.utils.safestring.mark_safe)

Comment: There you go, sorry for not posting it the first time

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to use

```
{{a|safe}}
```

in the template itself.

Comment: +1 Didn't know that. Anyways I like to keep templates as dumb as possible

Answer (score 0):

In the template file use {{a|safe}}, instead of {{a}}